# Removing specific characters and numbers from text string

Tags: r, string, character, gsub

I am working with retrosheet play by play data in RStudio and am trying to remove the non-pitching characters (i.e. pickoff attempts, balks, etc.) from the pitch sequence column. For example:

**Dataset I have:**

```
PITCH_SEQ_TX <- c('SSS.C', 'FFBB1', 'BBSSC', 'B.BSS2', 'CBSFFFS')
```

**Dataset I want:**

```
PITCH_SEQ_TX <- c('SSSC', 'FFBB', 'BBSSC', 'BBSS', 'CBSFFFS')
```

I need to figure out a way to remove the punctuation and numbers from the text string so that only letters remain. I've tried a couple of `gsub` function code lines, but can't seem to figure out the right combination. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are using R. Rstudio is an integrated developer's environment (IDE).

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
PITCH_SEQ_TX <- c('SSS.C','FFBB1','BBSSC','B.BSS2','CBSFFFS')
gsub("[[:punct:][:digit:]]+", "", PITCH_SEQ_TX)
```

Or to remove all non-alpha:

```
gsub("[^[:alpha:]]+", "", PITCH_SEQ_TX)
```

See the [R demo](http://ideone.com/7JpbKo)

The `[[:punct:][:digit:]]+` is a bracket expression that matches 1 or more (due to `+`) punctuation (`[:punct:]`) or digit (`[:digit:]`) characters, and the `[^[:alpha:]]` is a negated bracket expression that matches any char that is not a letter.